# How avoid scale for page-break and div sized in mm

Tags: html, css, page-break

We have badges. They are defined as a set of divs

```
break-after: page;
width: 85mm;
height: 54mm;
```

Height and width set in mm. We have to set the print scale to 99% so that the layout is correctly paginated.How to avoid scaling?

Answer (score 0):

We must set max-height and max-width

```
width: 85mm;
height: 54mm;
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 100vw;
```